# JavaScript: expand div to max height without getting scroll bars

Tags: javascript, html, height, scrollbar

I am working on a document with the structure like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http:http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Title</h1>

<div id="main">
<div id="head">Some text</div>
<div id="content"><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></div>
<div id="foot">Some more text (and a table)</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is, of course, a bit simplified, but shows the real structure of the document.

Now, I want to extend `#canvas` so that my document is as wide and as high as possible without anything getting out of the viewport (i.e., without getting scroll bars on my document).

CSS-only solutions are not O.K. for at least two reasons:

1. This is done dynamically, on request. Depending on some other factors, user may chose the content of `#canvas` to be bigger or smaller than that. What I want is a "Make optimal size" button (I know how to make the button itself -- this is only about determining the sizes).
2. The canvas element will not end up with the determined size, but slightly changed, to be a multiplier of some parameter, i.e., if `height` is the maximal allowable height we compute, the canvas will get its height actually set to `factor * Math.floor(height / factor)`.

I have managed to get the proper width using jQuery:

```
canvas.width = 0;
canvas.height = 0;

var t = $(canvas);
var w = $(window).width() - (t.outerWidth(true) - t.width());
$(canvas).parents().map(function() {
  t = $(this);
  w -= t.outerWidth(true) - t.width();
});
```

This simply takes the width of the viewport and chips away borders, paddings and margins of `#canvas` and all its parents, after setting `canvas` to size 0x0 (to prevent miscalculations if it is currently to wide and the document already has scrollbars). This works as intended, however, I've been unsuccessful in doing something similar for the height (and making it work and all modern browsers).

Among other things, I have tried using elements' `position().top` (which seems to behave differently in SeaMonkey, Chrome and Firefox) and I've tried playing with `$(window)`/`$(document)`/other elements' `height()`, `innerHeight()` and `outerHeight()`, but none of these worked.

**Edit:**

Maybe an additional explanation would help. The canvas is a gameboard. Think chess (although its not chess). So, the user can chose to play on a grid of mxn tiles (m,n being integers chosen via jQueryUI spins; each tile is `factor` wide and high). So, I want to give the user a button which would essentially say "make the board as big as possible without me needing to scroll while playing".

**Edit** (a possible solution)

This seems to do the trick:

```
h = window.innerHeight - $(main).position().top - $(main).outerHeight(true);
```

I've tested it under SeaMonkey (where `$(window).height()` was not working as expected), Firefox and Chrome. I have no way of testing IE newer than IE8 (where, as I expected, canvas itself doesn't work).

Comment: You could have the control you mention in your first reason for not doing this with CSS by having the code add/remove a class. But the second reason (sizing only in multiples of a number), sadly, is indeed something CSS doesn't offer yet...

Comment: Excsue me if im missunderstanding, but once you computed height you would just perform `$('canvas').css('height', computedHeight)` right?

Comment: @gbtimmon Actually, `canvas.height = computedHeight` (right before I draw on it), but it doesn't really matter, does it? It works like that for the width and I'm happy with it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The user is allowed to pick parameters as well. For example, if user picks "width" to be 17 and "height" to be 19, then `canvas` will be `17*factor` wide and `19*factor` high, regardless of the size of the viewport.

Comment: So are you saying you are having trouble computing the actual displayued height of the window? For instance `$('window').getHeightOfViewport()`? (If that existed which it doesnt)

Comment: @gbtimmon Isn't the viewport height given by `$(window).height()`, since I first reduce canvas to 0x0 to get the smallest possible document (and only then try to determine how high that canvas can become without the document getting higher than the viewport)?

Comment: Then it should be `$(window).height();`. What cases is this not working for you?

Comment: It didn't work properly under SeaMonkey.